# InDesign text frame layer with red padlock not showing in layers panel

Tags: adobe-indesign, layers

I have an InDesign .indd file for business cards that I can't edit any more. The layers are locked (have little red padlocks by them) but they're not showing in the Layers panel. The Layer *group* is showing and hiding the group hides the layers, but the layers themselves aren't showing so I can't unlock them.

[image: Screenshot of my indesign document]

(both objects are in the "Text" group and the view option for this group does hide/show the objects)

Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Comment: HI Rich Jenks, can you take a screenshot of your layers panel, I have never seen red padlocks before.

Comment: Hi Andrew, the padlocks are by the layers themselves rather than in the layers panel. I've added a screenshot to the description above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your text layer is on your master page. Open your Pages panel and double click on the A-Master page icon. You can also <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + Left Click to directly select the text frame even if you are not on the master page.

[image: pages panel screenshot]